# Rhythmbox, start from where I left

Tags: 22.04, rhythmbox

Is it possible to make Rhythmbox start from where it was when closed the last time? I have a music file that is close to 2 hours and I would like to resume from where I left. I have a few more files like 40 minutes, 90 minutes etc which I am trying to do the same. Sadly, I have to start from the beginning each time I start Rhythmbox. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

Any help will be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Rhythmbox does not have that feature. Other music player software does, such as Clementine, Audacious, SMPlayer.

Comment: Thanks for the info.